# Feature access service does not show fields by my arranged order

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, web-mapping, viewer

I have re-ordered the fields of my feature class on ArcMap 10.7 and published it as a hosted service, obviously with the feature access capability ticked on. I then took the REST endpoint and added to my webmap and saved. The issue now is that on the App / Map Viewer some fields when capturing the feature or Identifying a feature are not on the same order I have arranged on ArcMap. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How have you re-ordered your fields in ArcMap? Simply dragging them around the attribute table window? That does not actually re-order them at the database level. It's only saving a sort of "re-ordered view". See: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000024554

Comment: Thank you i managed to fix